# Error writing shell script for mongo db automation

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am using mongo db for my dashboard project. Now I have the following four steps to be followed in a row:

1. `cd scripts`
2. `node compiler.js`
3. type mongo and enter the mongodb
4. type `load('final_compiled.gen.js')`
5. call `mongo_function()`

I am able to follow til step 4 using the script. but I am unable to call mongo_function() using the script which is running in the mongo db context. Can anyone help me in doing this.Thank You......

Comment: Can you share your final_compiled.gen.js script?

Comment: @JamesWahlin it's a very long script. If you can share your email id woth me thn i can mail it to you. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily. first you have to enter all the commands that you want to run  in mongoDb context into javascript file and you  will have to write a shell script which just loads that javascript file into the mongo context.